# Twitter share button - need the HTML explained

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter

I have recently added a Share button into my random quote generator (http://conn3cted.uk.tn/quote.html) which works :-)

To make this work I had to add two things, one into my HTML file and one into my Javascript file...

## Javascript

```
twttr.widgets.createShareButton(
    // Do not share a URL
    " ",
    // Div where the share button should be inserted
    document.getElementById('tweetButton'),
    {
        // Define the tweet that will be used
        text: "'" + $(".quoteContent").text() + "'" +
        $(".quoteTitle").text(),
        // Set the size of the Twitter share button
        size: "large",
    }
);
```

## HTML

```
<script>window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    t = window.twttr || {};
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

  t._e = [];
  t.ready = function(f) {
    t._e.push(f);
  };

  return t;
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));</script>
```

I'm getting frustrated because I can't figure out what the HTML bit actually does...

Comment: explain your problem, and expected output?

Comment: That's probably because it's not HTML.  It's JavaScript.

Comment: The HTML part is just a `script` tag with some JavaScript.  Are you asking what that *JavaScript* code does?  It appears to be setting the `twttr` property on the `window` object.  Is there a particular line of code that is unclear?

Comment: i think your javascript  file is not properly included so html part is working

Comment: Sorry guys - I really didn't make my question clear! Everything is working fine, I just don't understand what the HTML bit actually does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "HTML" part creates a `<script>` to load the twitter widget library from https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js. It puts the created `<script>` element before all your scripts.

You can see the result in developer tools:

[image]

Let me know if you need more explanation.

**UPDATE**

Ok, so step by step. Look at first and last line:

```
<script>window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
...
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));</script>
```

It's a common pattern in JavaScript to declare a function and invoke it immediately. That's what happens here. First line is the declaration of a `function` that takes 3 params: `d`, `s` and `id`. In the last line the declared function is being called with actual parameters `document`, `"script"` and `"twitter-wjs"`. Additionally, result of the function is being assigned to `window.twttr` variable.

Let's move to the inside of function now:

```
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    t = window.twttr || {};
```

The 2 above lines declare 3 variables:

- `js` - undefined at this point
- `fjs` - equals to a first `<script>` element on the page (replace `d` and `s` with actual parameter values and you wil get: `document.getEelmentsByTagName("script")[0]`)
- `t` - equals to `window.twttr` if defined before or empty object `{}`

The next line is a protection from multiple includes of the twitter widget library:

```
if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
```

If element with `id="twitter-wjs"` already exists then return, i.e. break execution of the function. If it doesn't exist then move forward:

```
js = d.createElement(s);
js.id = id;
js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
```

The 3 lines create a `<script id="twitter-wjs" src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>` tag.

Next line inserts the created `<script>` as a first child of an element that contains first `<script>` in the document:

```
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
```

Following 3 lines:

```
t._e = [];
t.ready = function(f) {
  t._e.push(f);
};
```

initialize a queue to which you can put your functions and they will be invoked once the twitter widget is loaded. You can use it like this:

```
twttr.ready(function() {
    twttr.widgets.createShareButton(...);
});
```

Finally the last line returns the `t` variable as a result of the function.

```
return t;
```

Comment: Thank you for replying ;-) So that HTML is just loading a twitter widget so I can use the JS 'createShareButton' function (for example)?

I'd love to know exactly what that HTML is doing - I understand it's a function but I don't understand what most (or any) of the lines are actually doing. 

When learning new things I'm keen on getting to grips with what it's doing, at a really granular level, so it will help me later on.

Comment: Hey @user6038747, see my updated answer. I explained the code line by line.

Comment: That was perfect @Lukasz Wiktor, thank you!! I will need to read it a good 20 times but that is exactly what I was hoping for.